# Adding extra space to image GD

Tags: php, gd

im tring to do the same thing 9gag does to its images...

But so far, I just been able to add the watermark in top of the image, insted of adding the extra space to it...

And here is the original pic:
http://www.matamoros.gob.mx/test/595.jpg

This is my code:

```
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");

$img_name = "595.jpg";

$img_src = imagecreatefromjpeg($img_name);

$width_src = imagesx($img_src);

$height_src = imagesy($img_src);

$width_dst = $width_src;

$height_dst = $height_src;

$quality = 80;

$img = imagecreatetruecolor($width_src, $height_dst);

imagecopyresampled($img, $img_src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width_dst, $height_dst, $width_src, $height_src);

$x1_rect = 0;

$y1_rect = $height_dst - 30;

$x2_rect = $width_dst;

$y2_rect = $height_dst;

$color = imagecolorallocate($img, 245, 245, 245);

$letter_color = imagecolorallocate($img, 140, 140, 140);

$text = "http://en1.me/f/xxxxxxxx";

imagefilledrectangle($img, $x1_rect, $y1_rect, $x2_rect, $y2_rect, $color);

imagettftext($img, 20, 0, $x1_rect+5, $y1_rect+22, $letter_color, "Harabara.ttf", $text);

imagejpeg($img, '', $quality);

imagedestroy($img_src);

imagedestroy($img);
```

And this is the result:
http://www.matamoros.gob.mx/test/test2.php

As you can see, it places the information in top of the image... how can I make it so it places beneath the image?

Comment: in your test2.php, i see the info at the bottom. it looks like you found your solution. can you share it to everybody else who will come here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create new image 30px higher than source:

```
$img = imagecreatetruecolor($width_src, $height_dst + 30);
```

and place your text starting at the end of source image, filling all new space:

```
$y1_rect = $height_dst;
$y2_rect = $height_dst + 30;
```